# 'ckeditor' is not a known element Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ckeditor

I am working on an Ionic project. I am trying to integrate the [CKEditor module](https://ckeditor.com) on my project.

```
<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="content" editor="Editor">
</ckeditor>
```

I am getting an error though:

> 'ckeditor' is not a known element.

So, I tried some solutions, which I have found on the internet, but unfortunately, nothing worked for me.

I tried including the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` and `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`. I included the FormsModule, but no chance.

I was wondering, if you could help me, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please Share your Code.

Answer (score 1):

so i solved the problem. I did the following:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('editor1');
const ClassicEditor = require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic' );
ClassicEditor.create( document.getElementById( 'editor1' ) )
.then( editor => {
    console.log( editor );
} )
.catch( error => {
    console.error( error );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

install both these packages in your `angular` or `angular-ionic` app.

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular

npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

then import in module `app.module.ts`, and use it in component.

```
import * as CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editor',
  template: '<ckeditor [editor]="editor" [data]="summary"></ckeditor>',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-summary.component.scss']
})
export class EditorComponent {

  summary: string = `<p>Lorem ipsum</p>`
  public editor = CKEditor
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

> ### If ckeditor is not found then read following:

i.e. you have component `summary.component` and it is declared in `summary.module` then it is necessary to import `CKEditorModule` in `summary.module`.

let say you have `summary.module.ts` like:

```
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SummaryComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CKEditorModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    SummaryComponent
  ],
})
export class SummaryModule { }
```

then import `CKEditor` in `summary.component.ts`

```
import * as CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-summary',
  template: '<ckeditor [editor]="editor" [data]="summary"></ckeditor>',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-summary.component.scss']
})
export class EditSummaryComponent {

  summary: string = `<p>Lorem ipsum</p>`
  public editor = CKEditor
  constructor() {
  }
}
```